# ACF flyback clamp current issue

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

I study a paper.
There is a paper named "Design Consideration of MHz Active Clamp Flyback Converter with GaN Devices for Low Power Adapter Application"
I have a question about why changing the Cclamp value will have an impact on the current waveform.
As my understanding the iLk at the toff time the waveform should be like cosine, but when the Clamp is increased, the waveform doesn't like a cosine waveform.
[image]
[image]

For mathematic analysis, during this time, the circuit should be like the below figure, only L and C circuits. if this is only an L-C circuit why the current waveform doesn't like a cosine wave?

[image]

Comment: You are changing the resonant period and make it much larger than the off-time duration when you increase the clamp capacitor. What you see is no longer the resonating waveform but only a portion of it which looks like a ramp now. Remember, waveforms are approximated at an operating point where it makes sense for a correctly-designed ACF. Trying to push components values away from what they should reasonably be brings a variety of waveforms outside of the paper scope.